# How can I use just created build in downstream job

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jobs

I have 2 jobs in Jenkins:

1. Build and run unit tests
2. (Build and) run integration tests

*Job-2* is a Downstream project of *Job-1*.

*Job-1* initiates build and run unit tests on it.
*Job-2* initiates build as well and run integration tests.

I would like to change that, and **make *Job-2* to run the tests on the result build that was initiated by *Job-1*.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) and use Job-1 artifacts from Job-2 to run some tests on them. Refer to this [post](http://www.russellallen.info.gridhosted.co.uk/post/2011/06/04/Creating-a-Simple-Build-Pipeline-with-JenkinsHudson-and-NAnt.aspx) for more information. Hope it will help.